# What is the polite way to question someone's design on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion

Suppose I am answering someone's question on Stack Overflow, and I believe that they have a design flaw based on the substance of their question. Is it then appropriate to question their design and/or tell them their design is flawed? Or is this considered poor etiquette?

Comment: It's not poor etiquette if you do it politely (and usually, ideally in a comment rather than in an answer)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Telling someone that you think there is a better way of doing it is perfectly fine. If they don't want help or constructive criticism then they shouldn't be posting on here.

What I normally do is try to answer their particular question (if possible and assuming their design isn't completely hideous) then recommend the way I feel it should be done.

As far as *how* to tell them politely, probably don't use words like "stupid", "idiot", and "are you a moron".

> That is how it can be done the way you are trying. However, IMHO, this is a better approach to what you are doing.

But, remember, if you are going to tell them their design is flawed, you should be able to give reasons as to *why* it is flawed and *why/how* your approach is better. You can't expect them to just take your word for it. Provide details, examples, and or links if possible so they understand.

Answer (score 3):

If you have constructive criticism, the best thing to do is to leave a comment. As long as your comments polite, most people on SO will take the suggestion in the spirit in which it is intended. Once you've earned 50 reputation or more you can post a comment on any post. If you don't have enough reputation, then ask good questions, post good answers, or suggest good edits to raise your reputation.

Alternatively, if you have an alternative solution that's complete enough to answer the question and is a different from the other answers that have been offered in some meaningful way, you can post that as an answer yourself. And of course, it definitely helps to explain how your answer is different, and if you feel it's better than the other answers in some way, to explain why.

Comment: It doesn't even need to be better than the other answers, just different and informative. Answers are better than comments.

Comment: @djechlin You're right, I should have phrased that differently. Updated.